# android - How can I call a method in the MainActivity from another activity in C#?

Tags: c#, android

I want to call a method in the MainActivity class, from another activity.

I know it's done like this in Java:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).doSomething();
```

But I wanna know how it's done like in C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @P.B. well nothing because I don't know C#'s equivalent for the line of code I mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not create an instance of the activity class. It is wrong. Activity has ui and lifecycle and activity is started by startActivity(intent)

you can use this in Fragment to get activity context and run some function

In Java

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).doSomething();
```

In C#

```
((MainActivity)this.Activity).doSomething();
```